# Ending user agreement

Tags: usability

How to end user agreement or forcefully end such torture and deceptive practices that have been forced upon an intellectually challenged man. I want to end this now!

Comment: Are you trying to delete your profile on ux.stackexchange.com? If so, you can delete your profile by reading and completing the [Delete Profile](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/delete/116866) section of your profile settings.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the seriousness of your question, you have a few options:

- if it's too unbearable, disconnect your Internet. A lot of tortures will end instantaneously *(Disclaimer: withdrawal effects may follow)*
- hire a lawyer *(Disclaimer: might be expensive)*
- do the opposite of the agreements anyway *(Disclaimer: it might be something illegal)*
- Skip reading agreements altogether *(Disclaimer: you might potentially sell your first-born to a third-party)*

---

Serious suggestions:

- Outline only the main points of agreements when guiding a user through it
- Make use of simple graphics or icons
- Make use of simple and short sentences
- Try progressive disclosure with short explanations of agreement terms
- Don't let users proceed until you guide them through it all to make sure they don't agree to something they might not want to agree.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I just needed some air, know I’m not alone, there is an end to the means.